Rolling Average with variable min_periods from another column
I have a dataframe with multiple accounts across the last few years and am trying to get the rolling average of a column, per account, which is easy enough. However I also need to have the min_periods be variable. I have a column for the min_periods in the dataframe (minuploads) and the window is always 10. I just cannot find how to go about doing this. End of the day, I am trying to take a rolling average of the last 10 values, and each account falls into a different sort of category which requires a different minimum number of previous values which I have set as minuploads. If there are not enough previous values, I dont want the rolling average to calculate and will use a modeled value for those rows.
Here is a sample of the dataframe



accountID
date
diffs
minuploads




1001
2020-01-12
7
8


1001
2020-01-19
7
8


1001
2020-01-20
1
8


1001
2020-01-26
6
8


1002
2020-01-10
2
10


1002
2020-01-13
3
10


1002
2020-01-16
3
10


1002
2020-01-18
2
10



Initially I didnt use a variable min_periods and used this code for the rolling average:
df['ma'] = df.groupby('accountID')['diffs'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(10,5).mean())

Which worked great, but then decided I need to do a variable min_period. I tried this but I get a key error
df['ma'] = df.groupby('accountID')['diffs'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(10,x['minuploads']).mean())

Also tried this to make sure the groupby had both columns, but still get a KeyError: 'minuploads'
df['ma'] = df.groupby('accountID')[['diffs','minuploads']].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(10,x['minuploads']).mean())


Please make a reproducible pandas example. The version with min_periods=5 produces all NaNs since the groups only have 4 rows each.

minuploads shouldn't be a column because it's not per-row, it's per-account. You can just use a dict, or a Series if you prefer.
I've had to change the numbers to work with this example data. (8 and 10 to 2 and 3)
minuploads = {
    1001: 2,
    1002: 3,
}
df['ma'] = df.groupby('accountID')['diffs'].transform(
    lambda x: x.rolling(10, minuploads[x.name]).mean())

Result:
   accountID        date  diffs        ma
0       1001  2020-01-12      7       NaN
1       1001  2020-01-19      7  7.000000
2       1001  2020-01-20      1  5.000000
3       1001  2020-01-26      6  5.250000
4       1002  2020-01-10      2       NaN
5       1002  2020-01-13      3       NaN
6       1002  2020-01-16      3  2.666667
7       1002  2020-01-18      2  2.500000


Thanks! This was perfect. I had the minuploads in a different dataframe that was grouped by accountID, so I made a dictionary from that and applied your solution. Works exactly as I needed.
